# Appell Sequences as Group under Addition

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series

I was wondering if infinite polynomials sequences such as Appell Sequences could be groups under addition.

Take a polynomial sequence $\{p_n(x)\}$ where the following condition is imposed:
$$p'_n(x)=np_{n-1}(x)$$
Then if I take two sequences $\{p_n(x)\}$ and $\{q_n(x)\}$ and add them under the operation
$$\{p_n(x)\}+\{q_n(x)\}=\{(p+q)_n(x)\}$$
which is just point wise addition of corresponding sequence terms then it would be closed under this addition since
$$(p+q)'_n(x)=p'_n(x)+q'_n(x)=np_{n-1}(x)+nq_{n-1}(x)=n(p+q)_{n-1}(x)$$.
Associativity follows as well.  The identity would be $\{0\}=(0,0,0,...)$ and this surely satisfies the Appell condition 
and the inverse under addition would be $\{-p_n(x)\}$ since
$$-p'_n(x)=-np_{n-1}(x)$$

Is this a valid proof that the set of Appell Sequences is a group under Addition?  Is the addition well defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In fact, when the coefficients are in a commutative ring $R$, such things form an $R$-module.